# How to prevent quick clicking multiple controls?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am facing an issue to prevent quick multiple control clicking in Xamarin.Forms PCL project on Android. Basically I need to solve these four scenarios:

1. Clicking button and back button in NavigationBar
2. Clicking button and hardware back button
3. Clicking two or more buttons in the same time
4. Clicking same button multiple times

I use NavigationPage with 3 pages - MainPage, SecondPage and ThirdPage. On every page there are buttons handling navigation.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public async void NavigateToSecondPage(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
```

SecondPage.xaml.cs

```
    public async void NavigateToMainPage(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Are you really sure you want to navigate back?", "yes", "no"))
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    public async void NavigateToThirdPage(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ThirdPage());
    }
```

ThirdPage.xaml.cs

```
    public async void NavigateToSecondPage(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

First and Second scenario causes the issue, that MessageBox coming from SecondPage "NavigateToMainPage" event handler is on the MainPage. Third scenario is similar, but MessageBox from SecondPage is on the ThirdPage. Last scenario causes stacking same page multiple times on NavigationStack.

Is there any solution, which covers all these scenarios? This question is also for native Android developers.

[Solution replicating issue](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As1Bb4lGxggCg9cLlkOQDMNd0TA8fA)

[Gif representing scenario 1 & 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euoxw.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a global boolean "canClick". Set it to true by default. when clicking, check if it is false. If false, do nothing (another click is being handled), if true, set it false, start what you do usually on that button, then set it true again when done (to handle future clicks).

As you are doing async methods, you may have to set the variable public and static to access it from your "FirstPage" "SecondPage" ... objects in order to set it false when loaded correctly.

Alternative way consists into two custom functions "allowClicks()" and "forbidClicks()". disable all buttons on forbidClicks, enable them in allowClicks. Call forbid when the user click on a button, then allow button when your treatment is done. Depending on your treatment, you may have to make these functions statics (and that could be impossible).

I hope this helps.

edit:code sample.

```
public static void disableButtons() {
    button1.setEnabled(false);
    button2.setEnabled(false);
    button3.setEnabled(false);
    button4.setEnabled(false);
}
public static void enableButtons() {
    button1.setEnabled(true);
    button2.setEnabled(true);
    button3.setEnabled(true);
    button4.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then you call yourClass.disableButtons(); on each button click. Then "yourClass.enableButtons();" after treatment done. I can't be more precise because i don't know if you are fully using android (then, you have an activity somewhere), if your "Pages" are activities or fragments... etc.

The rest of the code depends on it. If each page is an activity, i'm almost sure that's more complicated as it is unsafe to do UI changes on paused activities. If Pages are fragments, you may have to use interfaces and fragment functions instead of static functions.

You are not precise enought on what you are doing so i can't be more precise in code.

However, let's try like i said first, assuming you have only one activity and each pages are "layouts" of this activity (not fragments). Code will be like that :

```
private boolean canClick=true;
```

in onCreate():

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(canClick) {
            canClick=false;
            /*show your other page here
            if showing is ascync, canClick=true; must be done AFTER showing, use services, handlers, 
            here i assume nothing is async, so i put canClick=true; directly after treatment
            */
            canClick=true;
        }
    }
});
```

And you use the same code for each button, customing each treatment like you want. You can also replace "canClick=false;" by "disableButtons();" and "canClick=true" by "enableButtons();" and remove the if statement if you are using functions like my code above.

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide me the code how would you solve all scenarios?

Comment: @Jan Look answer edit. I can't be more precise because i don't know xamarin forms, neither the program lifecycle. So i made it like if it was only on android, and no fragment involved. If fragments (or equivalents) are involved, or if each page is an activity (or equivalent) things because more complicated. However i'm almost sure if you were using different activities as pages problem would not occurs.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. How would you cover first scenario? Clicking on the button and then immediatly on back button in NavigationBar? Is there any event to subscribe for back button? I know there is an event to hardware back button, but I couldn't find any event to subscribe event for back button in NavBar.

Comment: if you mean action bar, it is "public void onBackPressed()" from activity. you can call it from a fragment using "getActivity().onBackPressed();". If you ever override it, don't forget to call super.onBackPressed() if you don't handle the even so the user will be able to finish activity without killing app.